# MAM: Can stored data in restricted mode be revoked at any time?

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging

I have stored some data on the Tangle using MAM in restricted mode.
Can this existing stored data be revoked, at any time, in some way? 
In the MAM API I could not find such an option.
Note: I am not talking about changing the sideKey.

Here are my alternative (NOT OPTIMAL) solutions:
1) Add a validity dateTime to the stored data. After this dateTime the stored data should not be used.
2) Add a link to the stored data. The receiver of this data should check this link if the data is revoked.

Answer (score 3):

When storing data on the Tangle using MAM, you actually issue 0 value transactions that encapsulate your data. As such, it is impossible to revoke the data once published. By throwing away the side key, you make it impossible to find the tx and decrypt it.

[Here](https://medium.com/@abmushi/iota-mam-eloquently-explained-d7505863b413) is some nice material for MAM, it may clear things out.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with „throwing away“ ? I guess people I gave the sideKey in the past still can read my message.